# Tell Travis to skip a test, but continue to include it in my main test suite?

Tags: django, travis-ci

I am using Django 1.8 and I have a management command that geocodes some items in my database, which requires an internet connection.

I have written a test for this management command. However, the test runs the script, so it also requires an internet connection.

After pushing the test to GitHub, my CI is broken, because Travis doesn't have an outside internet connection so it fails on this test.

I want to keep this test, and I'd like to continue to include it in `python manage.py test` when run locally.

However, is there a way I can explicitly tell Travis not to bother with this particular test?

Alternatively, is there some other clean way that I can keep this test as part of my main test suite, but stop it breaking Travis?

Comment: 'Travis doesn't have an outside internet connection' -- I have a test that require an internet connection and it passes just fine. On the other hand, I also have a method that attempts to resolve a DOI URL (http://www.doi.org) and its test fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you could decorate your test with `@unittest.skipIf(condition, reason)` to test for the presence of a [Travis CI specific environment variable](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables) to skip it or not. For example:

```
import os
...
@unittest.skipIf("TRAVIS" in os.environ and os.environ["TRAVIS"] == "true", "Skipping this test on Travis CI.")
def test_example(self):
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach. I'll try it and report back.

Comment: The above works, but in case you're using `tox` as your test runner, you'll want to make sure there is a `passenv = TRAVIS` in your `tox.ini` to allow the ENV var to propagate to the text environment.

Comment: A much shorter notation would be:
`@unittest.skipIf(os.environ.get('TRAVIS') == 'true', 'Skipping this test on Travis CI.')`

Answer (score 0):

If the external resource is an HTTP endpoint, you should consider using [vcrpy](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy) to record and replay the HTTP requests/responses.

This way you can continue running the same test suite in different environments. It'll also speed this test up.